# Benefit of randomly generated column names?

Tags: databases

Would it be of any benefit to have tables with randomly generated names?

For example:

An SQL injection might be looking for:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1=1`

But if `users` is really `rifchodafsnhe` (or some other nonsense) their injection wouldn't work.

**Question: pros vs cons of gibberish column names from a security vs usability standpoint**

Comment: I think this falls more under the category of security by obscurity which I don't think is ever a good idea. The readability of source code is going to be definitely affected, which I don't even think is a good trade-off in terms of risk vs functionality.

Comment: SQL injection can be prevented if using the right coding principles, i.e. [use parameter binding](http://bobby-tables.com/). This is not that hard and much safer than using "random" column names which eventually will leak anyway.

Comment: To the downvoter: just because the idea presented in the question is bad doesn't mean it is a bad question.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't intending on actually _using_ this for security. Just a thought I wanted to get feedback on here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Security by obscurity is not always bad, but here I think it is.

The correct way to judge a security mechanism/implementation/control is "Does it impose more of a burden on the legitimate user than on the illegitimate user?, and is the burden disproportionate to the benefit?"

This poses a significant burden on the legitimate user and makes it rather likely that the legitimate user will misremember/misunderstand the answer and reach a bad conclusion.

I find the single mis-use case you pose to be unpersuasive.  (Others may disagree, but for me, the value is not worth the cost).

Answer (score 4):

Your suggestion is analogous to hiding your weed stash in the floorboards of your house.

**Pros:** Barely any. Your mom won't find it, but when the dogs come sniffing around, they sure will.

**Cons:** What a hassle when you just want a joint.

Comment: Amazing analogy!